# Should EF entites contains additional fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, design-patterns, architecture

I'm using EntityFramework as my DAL, where I have for example entity:

```
public class UserEntity
{
    public int WorkingDays {get;set;}
}
```

I'm getting this entity in my services layer by repository, and that's the place i need to calculate for example his salary:

```
public ???? GetUserWithPayments(int id)
{
    var userEntity = _userRepository.GetUser(id);
    var payPerDieValue = _paymentService.GetValue();

    var salary = userEntity.WorkingDays * payPerDieValue;

  //*what should i return??*//
}
```

And now I have no idea what should I return from this method? I see 2 options:

1.) Add salary field to UserEntity, and returns UserEntity. This field will be skipped when I save UserEntity to database.

2.) Create UserDto with UserEntity fields and one more Salary

This service is called by UserController where the result will be mapped to GetUserDetailsViewModel

Comment: Yes, create a DTO/ViewModel. Keep your entity model clean (Single Responsibility).

Comment: @SteveGreene, I got ViewModel in controllers. So Repository should Return UserEntity, then in service I should return UserDTO, and then from controller UserViewModel. So I should have 3 layers of models right? Every layer its own data model?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need salary property at UserEntity, because it will be duplication of data. Eventually make a property

```
[NotMapped]
public decimal Salary => WorkingDays * PayPerDay;
```

Notice that it is not mapped, so that it is not inserted into database, but calculated on each call.

P.S. I see you use int, but it is more natural to use decimal for PayPerDay, since salary doesn't have to be integer. Also, you want to include a possibility that someone will work half a day and still be paid for that.

Comment: Hi, i just edited the question. It's just example entity to understand my point.

Comment: Return just UserEntity. It will have calculated salary at UserEntity.Salary property.

Comment: Will not have, take a look at the question again. There is no more PayPerDay in UserEntity. My first example was wrong, now is correctly describing my problem

Comment: You can return Tuple<UserEntity, salary> where second field is salary.